# How do I code the header in AdaptiveTheme?

Tags: theming

How can I code the header in AdaptiveTheme subtheme that it allows me to have the branding floating left, the navbar on the right etc.
I know that I can add some classes in the page.tpl that floats as I wish, but is this correct way to go?

AdaptiveTheme seems to promote the use of "regions", however when I add the Menu Bar in the "Header-region" it goes below the branding -- and the "nav" class is not applied to the menu bar. So it looks like a normal list, however If I place it in the Menu region it seems to look like a menu and the "nav class" is applied, where do I control this behavior?

What is the "correct" way to, add "grids" in the header, allowing for different navs/logo, etc.

I looked at panels, but quickly reading it seems to be focused on content rather than the layout structure, am I right or wrong here?

Comment: This is a broadly-phrased question. To help people, what is your familiarity with themeing in Drupal? Also, be mindful what your device responsive strategy is as this will affect how you'll add elements.